# What is this method called - Abelization of a Group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Today, I wanted to make a post for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417691/8581). There are some approach in which we can overcome the problem like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/417751/8581) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59314/8581). According to my knowledge, I could solve the problem via the approach I had learned. Since I don't know *what is this way called*, so I refused to post an answer. I am very thankful if somebody tells me **what is the method named?**  Here is some of the preliminaries but not the whole things because it is difficult for me to translate whole story (sorry).

> **Definition:** Let $R=\{r_1,r_2,...,r_m\}$, $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and $G=\langle X| R\rangle$. And consider the abelian group $G/G'$. If $\alpha_{ij}$ be the sum of the powers of $x_j$ in relation $r_i$ so we can call the following matrix, the **relation matrix** of abelian group $G/G'$: $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
>   \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & ... & \alpha_{1n}\\
>   \alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} & ... & \alpha_{2n}\\
>   \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
>   \alpha_{m1} & \alpha_{m2} & ... & \alpha_{mn}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> **Definition:** Let $G=\langle X| R\rangle$, such that $|X|-|R|\le 0$. If we can make $M$ to have an standard diagonal form: $$D:=\begin{pmatrix}
>   d_1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
>   0 & d_2 & ... & 0 & 0\\
>   0 & 0 & d_3 &0 & 0\\
>   \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &d_k\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}_{m\times n}$$ wherein $d_i\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$, by employing elementary row operations, then we can have $G/G'\cong\mathbb Z_{d_1}\times\mathbb Z_{d_2}\times...\mathbb Z_{d_k}$.
>
> **For example:** Let $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^{2^{n-1}}=1, a^{2^{n-2}}=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$$ so $$G/G'=\langle a,b\mid a^{2^{n-1}}=1, a^{2^{n-2}}=b^2, a^2=1, [a,b]=1\rangle$$ Now we have $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
>   2^{n-1} & 0\\
>   2^{n-2} & -2\\
>   2 &0\\
>  \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_3\leftrightarrow R_1}\begin{pmatrix}
>   2 & 0\\
>   2^{n-2} & -2\\
>   2^{n-1} &0\\
>  \end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}
>   2 & 0\\
>   0 & -2\\
>   0 &0\\
>  \end{pmatrix}$$ So $G/G'\cong\mathbb Z_{2}\times\mathbb Z_{2}$.

Thanks for your time reading my question. :)

Comment: In response to your comments elsewhere, this method is new to me. Although it is rather nice.

Comment: @user1729: I am so glad I could bring up here a new thing. :)

Comment: @MathsLover: Likewise, Happy one to you and your family. ;-)

Comment: This is what I call great question ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called computing the Smith normal form, and the application you describe features in this question: [Determining the Smith Normal Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144589/determining-the-smith-normal-form)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an Application of the main structure theorem of finitely generated modules over a P.I.D applied to the case of abelian groups. If you have Jacobson algebra book go to page 188 (Ch. 3.10 "application to abelian groups and to linear transformations") I don't see a specific name for this method here, but it is well explained.