# Element of Infinite Order of Finitely Presented Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be finitely presented group with $n$ generators and $r$ relations where $n>r$. I want to show that $G$ has an element with infinite order.

My attempt:

Assume that $F_n$ is free group with $n$ generators. We know that $F_n/F^{\prime}_n\cong\mathbb Z ^n$. So $F_n$ has an element of infinite order, but I don't know how use the relations?

Comment: A homogeneous system of linear equations with more unknowns than equations has a nonzero solution. Use this to show that $G$ has a nontrivial homomorphism onto ${\mathbb Z}$ and deduce the result.

Comment: @DerekHolt, how?

Comment: Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be the group generators. Then $a_i \mapsto x_i$ (with $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$) extends to a homomorphism $G \to {\mathbb Z}$ if and only if the $x_i$ satisfy the $r$ group relations, or equivalently if the $x_i$ satisfy $r$ homogeneous linear equations. Since $n>r$, these equations have a nonzero solution in ${\mathbb Q}$ and hence also in ${\mathbb Z}$, so we get a nontrivial homomorphism $G \to {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thanks for solution. Does a finitely presented group exist such that it has an element with infinite order for case n<r?

Comment: @user108209, one way of doing it is by making sure that one of the generators does not occur in any of the relations.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478841/finitely-presented-group-with-fewer-relations-than-generators?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider the abelianisation of your group. This is a finitely generated abelian group, and you want to prove that its decomposition contains a $\mathbb{Z}$-term. Consider your abelian group as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, form an appropriate matrix and diagonalise. What do you notice?

Sorry, I do not got the time to expand on this more just now. But my point is basically: compute the abelinisation, and do what you see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418353/what-is-this-method-called-abelization-of-a-group). What do you notice?

Comment: Can you explain more?