# Extra Operation required for Smith Normal Form over PID-Theoretical Justification

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, matrix-decomposition

Why does one need an extra operation for performing smith normal form over a PID? One might suspect and say that it is because of the lack of Euclidean algorithm or just say that we need the additional operation to get what we need.

But I cannot exactly see what property of Euclidean domain makes the fourth operation unnecessary. I would also like to know how this is justified theoretically? Thanks

Comment: You might get a better answer sooner if you say what your operations are.

Comment: I believe the operations used for Smith normal form are well known.

Comment: It can be found here for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133076/computing-the-smith-normal-form